# Google Maps API V3 pinch-to-zoom does not work with IE 11 on Windows 8.1 preview

Tags: javascript, google-maps, multi-touch, pinchzoom, windows-8.1

Trying to use pinch-to-zoom on multitouch screen with Windows 8.1 preview and Internet Explorer 11 (IE later on) does not work with Google Maps API V3 (none of the latest versions: 3.12, 3.13 and 3.14). The expected behaviour is map zooming in and out.

The same feature is working just fine with Windows 8 and IE 10.

There seem to be two exceptions for the case:

- https://maps.google.com
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple (any example being embedded in the docs pages; when viewed in a standalone tab or window by pressing the view "full screen" pinch-to-zoom does not work)

Does anyone know how that is achieved so that it could be used until the issue is fixed?

Comment: It doesn't work on mouse scroll wheel as well. It seems to happen in anything full-screen-ish. I tried here: [link]https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/map-coordinates[/link]

Comment: Regarding the mouse scroll issue please upvote: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5944

Comment: Regarding pinch-to-zoom upvote the following issue: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5747

Answer (score 0):

For the time being you can add this meta tag to your head tag (make sure it's the first tag after the head)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" />
```

That will fix the problem for IE 11 users because the browser will behave as an IE 10 browser.

When Google fixes the [bug](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5747) you can put it back to IE=edge or just remove it.

**EDIT :** The bug has been fixed by now

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I add this right after <head> (or even after </head>) and pinch to zoom still does not work.

Comment: It's already fixed now in the experimental version
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple